# trying to install via conda throws glibc version error

Tags: linux, conda

I am trying to install a conda package on a virtual machine on my mac and I keep getting this error that I dont understand.

```
conda install -c "formicidae-tracker/label/test" py-fort-myrmidon

ERROR
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found                    
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:  
                                                                               
Specifications:                                                                
                                                                               
  - py-fort-myrmidon -> python[version='>=3.8,<3.9.0a0']                       
                      
Your python: python=3.9.0

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0
  - feature:|@/linux-64::__glibc==2.31=0

Your installed version is: 2.31
```

Comment: Also having this problem, but with python 3.10.